# how to solve PFC FiPy imported gmsh, which is converted from .msh Ansys format, error

Tags: python-2.7, mesh, fipy

what is the problem for meshing in PFC software by importing .msh2 mesh type by FiPy.grid3D("")?
this mesh is exported from openFOAM and converted to the readable .msh for FiPy. Embedded FiPy version is 3.1 and Python version is 2.7.

```
IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<itasca-code-0-19def0f6e02e>", line 116, in <module>
  File "<itasca-code-0-19def0f6e02e>", line 11, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\factoryMeshes.py", line 111, in Grid3D
    if numerix.getShape(dx) == ()   File "C:\Program Files\Itasca\PFC500\exe64\python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\tools\numerix.py", line 242, in getShape
    raise AttributeError, "No attribute 'shape'"
AttributeError: No attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand, but `Grid3D` does not parse Gmsh meshes. You want [`Gmsh3D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#fipy.meshes.gmshMesh.Gmsh3D).